# What is the Twig equivalent of isset() and !empty()?

Tags: php, twig

What is the Twig equivalent of the below PHP ternary condition?

```
<?php echo (isset($myVar) && !empty($myVar)) ? $myVar : '#button-cart'; ?>
```

I have ingloriously tried this but it doesn't look good and of course, it doesn't work:

```
{{ myVar is defined and myVar not empty ? myVar : '#button-cart' }}
```

Comment: `isset($myVar) && !empty($myVar)` is __redundant__. Just `!empty($myVar)` is __enough__

Comment: You are missing the `is` in your second test. Either do `is myVar not empty` or `myvar is not empty` whatever floats your boat

Comment: @u_mulder In `twig` it's not reduntant. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/ppwudu)

Comment: @DarkBee now go and see `compiled` block. Do you see that `defined` checks with `array_key_exists`?

Comment: I sure did @u_mulder, but just checking `myVar is empty` will give OP a runtime error. Just pointing this out the double check in twig is necessary

Comment: @DarkBee okay, you're right.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See [Tests](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/index.html) for all tests. To use a test, use `variable is test`. You're missing 'is' in your 'empty' test. Credits to @DarkBee for pointing out that little mistake.

But to answer your initial question, take a look at [Twig/Extension/Core.php](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php).That class shows how every Twig test works 'under the hood'.

Here is a small table with all tests and their PHP equivalent:

```
| Twig test    | PHP method used                                   |
|--------------|---------------------------------------------------|
| constant     | constant                                          |
| defined      | defined                                           |
| divisible by | %                                                 |
| empty        | twig_test_empty                                   |
| even         | % 2 == 0                                          |
| iterable     | $value instanceof Traversable || is_array($value) |
| null         | null ===                                          |
| odd          | % 2 == 1                                          |
| same as      | ===                                               |
```

`twig_test_empty` checks:

- if it's an array: `count(array) === 0` or
- if it's an object: `Object::__toString === ''` or
- if it's something else (for example string, float or integer): `'' === $value || false === $value || null === $value || array() === $value`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The issue was indeed a missing `is` in the `empty` test. Credits to @DarkBee too.