# Missing twig tags in script tag

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, twig

I have a problem with mixing twig and jQuery. I try to implement fullcallendar. Everything works locally, but fails on remote server. This is part of my admin.html.twig:

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                    minTime: '08:00:00',
                    maxTime: '21:00:00',
                    defaultTimedEventDuration: '01:00:00',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
                    }, 
                    events: {% if calendarData is defined %}
                                {{ calendarData|json_encode|raw }}
                            {% else %}
                                null
                            {% endif %}
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I can get the events on localhost, but on the remote server 'view source' shows this:

```
                    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                    minTime: '08:00:00',
                    maxTime: '21:00:00',
                    defaultTimedEventDuration: '01:00:00',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
                    }, 
                    events:                                     
                                                });
            });
        </script>
```

Why?

Comment: Weird, could you dump the value of `calendarData` on the remote server?

Comment: Interesting. Even if `calendarData` is `null` or `false`, `json_encode()` would return the value as a string. And an empty string would be returned as `""`. The only way to reproduce this behavior is `echo json_encode();`, which equals to an undefined variable. It would be interesting to see if `{% if calendarData is defined and calendarData %}` goes to the else condition and print `null`. But the error is most likely not the twig, but the value of `calendarData`.

Comment: {{ dump(calendarData) }} not working.

Comment: The `is defined` does **not** account for variables being null. The correct `if` would be in fact `{% if calendarData is defined and calendarData %}`

Comment: [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436858/what-is-the-twig-equivalent-of-isset-and-empty)

Comment: Ok, I have no clue if it has something to do with the prod mode or server config , anyway twig tags are being completly ignored inside <script>. Looks like I need to rewrite the whole thing and use ajax.